# I am having trouble calculating the x and y values for my bullets in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to create a game in python using pygame. In my game you are a man and there are many zombies around you who you must shoot, however I cannot understand how to make my character shoot a bullet in the direction of the mouse at a set speed each time. My game is 2D and has a top down view of the sprites on the screen.

The code will look something like this:

```
class bullet:
       def __init__(self, x, y, speed):
               self.x = x
               self.y = y
               self.speed = speed
       def move(self):
               This is where you guys come in
       def draw(self):
               pygame.draw.circle(screen,(0,0,0),(self.x,self,y,5)
```

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Try looking up Vector Normalisation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to know the `angle` or if not you need an explicit `x_speed` and `y_speed` ...

if you have the angle you can calculate it

```
x_speed = math.cos(angle)*speed
y_speed = math.sin(angle)*speed
```

then at each step

```
new_x = old_x + x_speed
new_y = old_y + y_speed
```

you can get the angle with math.atan2

```
angle = math.atan2(character.x-mouse.x,character.y-mouse.y)
```

Comment: thanks! This lead my to the correct answer. You need to minus the xspeed btw :)